# How to output GeoJSON file from MySQL database shapefile?

Tags: geojson, php, mysql-spatial

I have a MySQL spatial database ('mydb') of one table ('tst'), I mean by spatial. I need to output the GeoJSON file from this spatial MySQL table. I downloaded geoPHP library and also MySQL to GeoJSON script which I adapted to my database settings, like below:

```
<?php
/**
* Title:   MySQL to GeoJSON (Requires https://github.com/phayes/geoPHP)
* Notes:   Query a MySQL table or view and return the results in GeoJSON format, suitable for use in OpenLayers, Leaflet, etc.
* Author:  Bryan R. McBride, GISP
* Contact: bryanmcbride.com
* GitHub:  https://github.com/bmcbride/PHP-Database-GeoJSON
*/

# Include required geoPHP library and define wkb_to_json function
include_once('geoPHP/geoPHP.inc');
function wkb_to_json($wkb) {
    $geom = geoPHP::load($wkb,'wkb');
    return $geom->out('json');
}

# Connect to MySQL database
$conn = new PDO('mysql:host=localhost;dbname=mydb','root','test123');

# Build SQL SELECT statement and return the geometry as a WKB element
$sql = 'SELECT *, AsWKB(SHAPE) AS wkb FROM mytable';

# Try query or error
$rs = $conn->query($sql);
if (!$rs) {
    echo 'An SQL error occured.\n';
    exit;
}

# Build GeoJSON feature collection array
$geojson = array(
   'type'      => 'FeatureCollection',
   'features'  => array()
);

# Loop through rows to build feature arrays
while ($row = $rs->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)) {
    $properties = $row;
    # Remove wkb and geometry fields from properties
    unset($properties['wkb']);
    unset($properties['SHAPE']);
    $feature = array(
         'type' => 'Feature',
         'geometry' => json_decode(wkb_to_json($row['wkb'])),
         'properties' => $properties
    );
    # Add feature arrays to feature collection array
    array_push($geojson['features'], $feature);
}
header('Content-type: application/json');
//write to json file
$fp = fopen('mytable_geojson.json', 'w');
fwrite($fp, json_encode($geojson));
fclose($fp);
$conn = NULL;
?>
```

But when I execute the code on the browser they show that:

```
    out('json'); } 
# Connect to MySQL database 
$conn = new PDO('mysql:host=localhost;dbname=mydb','root','test123'); 
# Build SQL SELECT statement and return the geometry as a WKB element 
$sql = 'SELECT *, AsWKB(SHAPE) AS wkb FROM mytable'; 
# Try query or error 
$rs = $conn->query($sql); 
if (!$rs) { echo 'An SQL error occured.\n'; exit; } 
# Build GeoJSON feature collection array 
$geojson = array( 'type' => 'FeatureCollection', 'features' => array() ); 
# Loop through rows to build feature arrays 
while ($row = $rs->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)) { $properties = $row; 
# Remove wkb and geometry fields from properties 
unset($properties['wkb']); 
unset($properties['SHAPE']);
 $feature = array( 'type' => 'Feature', 'geometry' => json_decode(wkb_to_json($row['wkb'])), 'properties' => $properties ); 
# Add feature arrays to feature collection array 
array_push($geojson['features'], $feature); } header('Content-type: application/json'); 
//write to json file 
$fp = fopen('mytable_geojson.json', 'w'); 
fwrite($fp, json_encode($geojson)); 
fclose($fp); 
$conn = NULL; ?>
```

Comment: I've tried to recover the format of the second block of output but there's a chance I've messed it up - but at least its readable now. Please try and format your pasted code and output for legibility.

Comment: @Spacedman thanks so much

Answer (score 1):

Late but hoping it would help someone.
**Without using geoPHP library**:

```
getGeoJSON.php:    
// Connect to MySQL database
    $conn = new PDO('mysql:host=localhost;dbname=mydb','root','test123');

    // Build SQL SELECT statement and return the 'shape' as GeoJSON
    $sql = 'SELECT
             *,
             ST_AsGeoJSON(SHAPE) AS shape
             FROM mytable';

    // Try query or error
    $rs = $conn->query($sql);
    if (!$rs) {
        echo 'An SQL error occured.\n';
        exit;
    }

     // save features in list
        while ($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($rs)) {
            $listeAttributes[] = array(
                "X1" => $row["X1"],
                "X2" => $row["X2"],
                "Xn" =>$row["Xn"],
                "shape" => $row["shape"]
            );
        }

// open a <script> tag for writte JS code

<script>
// Encode the feature list on JSON format
 var list_elements = <?php echo(json_encode($isteAttributes)) ?>;

// Function for get the GeoJSON
function getGeoJSON(list_features) {
    var geoJSON = {
        "type": "FeatureCollection",
        "features": [],
    };

// loop through the elements of the list
for(var i = 0; i < list_features.length; i++) {
        var element = list_features[i];
        // Create the feature object
        var feature = {
            "type": "Feature",
            "geometry": {},
            "properties": {}
        };
        for(var key in element) {

                    if(key == "shape") {
                        // getting the geometry
                        feature.geometry = JSON.parse(element[key]);
                    }
                    else {
                        // For the other columns we add them in 'properties'
                        feature.properties[key] = element[key];
                    }
                }
                // Once the feature is created, we add it to the "features" key of our "geoJSON" object
                geoJSON.features.push(feature);
            }

        return geoJSON;
    }

// Pass the list to the function and verify
    console.log('the output geojson: ');
    var geojson_res = getGeoJSON(list_elements);
    console.log(geojson_res);

</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

如何從 MySQL 資料庫使用 geometry 型態儲存wkt多邊形的 shapefile 輸出成 GeoJSON 格式文件?

PHP CODE:

```
<?php
// .... 

echo geoJson(getData());

function geoJson($data){
$geojson = array(
    'type' => 'FeatureCollection',
    'crs' => array(
        "type"  => "name",
        "properties" => array("name" => "")
    ),
    'features' => array()
);
$features = array();
foreach($data as $key => $feature){
    $features[] = array(
        "type" => "Feature", 
        "properties" => array(
            "名稱" => $feature['name'], 
            "時間" => $feature['time'], 
        ), 
        "geometry" => $feature['wkt']
    );
}
$geojson['features'] = $features;
return toGeoJson($geojson);
}

function getData(){
$sql = 'SELECT xxxxx,xxxxx, time, ST_AsGeoJSON(geometry) as wkt 
FROM xxxxx';
$data =  $your_sql_orm->fetch();

/* the output data form you db like:
Array
(
[0] => Array
    (
        [name] => RXXXXXX1
        [time] => 2023-xxx-xxxx
        [wkt] => {"type": "Polygon", "coordinates": [[[120, 22], [120.3, 22.6], [120.37, 22.69], [120.37, 22.7], [120, 22]]]}
    )
[1] => Array
    (
        [name] => RXXXXXX2
        [time] => 2023-xxx-xxxx
        [wkt] => {"type": "Polygon", "coordinates": [[[100.9, 23.8], [118.21, 23.13], [118.3, 23.06], [119.2, 23.57], [100.9, 23.8]]]}
    )
[2] => Array
....
*/
return $data;
}

/** Code by Arter */
function toGeoJson($arr){
header('Content-type: application/json');
$json = json_encode($arr, JSON_PRETTY_PRINT|JSON_UNESCAPED_SLASHES|JSON_HEX_QUOT|JSON_HEX_TAG|JSON_HEX_AMP|JSON_HEX_APOS);
// 由於陣列內會產生多餘的反斜線，故取代移除 
// 如："{\"type\": \"Polygon\", \"coordinates\":
$json = str_replace('\u0022', '"', $json);
$json = str_replace('"{', '{', $json);
$json = str_replace('}"', '}', $json);
return $json;
}
```

And Outupt a GeoJson format:

```
{
    "type": "FeatureCollection",
    "crs": { 
        "type": "name", 
        "properties": {
            "name": "urn:ogc:def:crs:OGC:1.3:CRS84"
        }
    },
    "features": [
        {
            "type": "Feature", 
            "properties": { 
                "名稱": "RXXXXXX1", 
                "時間": "2023-xxx-xxxx"
            }, 
            "geometry": {"type": "Polygon", "coordinates": [[[120, 22], [120.3, 22.6], [120.37, 22.69], [120.37, 22.7], [120, 22]]]}
        },
        {
            "type": "Feature", 
            "properties": { 
                "名稱": "RXXXXXX2", 
                "時間": "2023-xxx-xxxx"
            }, 
            "geometry": {"type": "Polygon", "coordinates":  [[[100.9, 23.8], [118.21, 23.13], [118.3, 23.06], [119.2, 23.57], [100.9, 23.8]]]}
        }
    ]
}
```

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).